# In AngularJS, is there a way to disable the prevention of default action when a form is missing the action attribute?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

In my code, I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

By default, AngularJS [disables form submissions](http://docs.angularjs.org/#dsq-login-google) without an action attribute specified. I understand I can (and should) assign a form action, however I'd like to know if there's a simple way to prevent AngularJS from intercepting this specific form submission event so that it can post normally.

Comment: Post to where? `action=""` is the same as no action at all.

Comment: action="" will post to the current page

Comment: I'm still confused, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I *think* you're trying to get forms with action="" to behave like other forms in angular? If so, I have an answer, if not, disregard.

Comment: I'm trying to get the form to post back to itself. If the form is on a page with the URL of "/users", it normally posts back to "/users". However, AngularJS prevents that from happening (see documentation). I want to tell AngularJS that it actually should act like a normal form, and post back to itself.

Comment: Then why not use action=""?

Comment: Because, as I mention in the question, AngularJS prevents action="" from posting.

Comment: ahh... I get it now... you can just put junk in there like: action=" " or action="?" ... it's because Angular is checking for `!attr.action`, which, thanks to JavaScript is `true` for "".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `action="?"` ... Angular is checking `!attr.action`, which if action == "", is true.